# how to use dnsmasq to block site and show blocked page?

Tags: linux, https, dns, debian, server

- I have **dnsmasq** on **Debian**

  **and I use it as DNS server.**

Is there a way to block some site like **Facebook** , **twitter** and show HTML page saying this site is blocked?

the network type is:

1. wireless router
2. some LAN pc
3. and the dns server
4. some wireless pc

Answer (score 1):

The method is called DNS spoofing. But it is pointless since users can happily change their machine's DNS settings to OpenDNS or Google to bypass yours'.

This is the way nevertheless. Update your /etc/hosts or /etc/dnsmasq.hosts (depending on the way you've configured your dnsmasq):
192.168.0.10 facebook.com
192.168.0.10 twitter.com

Then run a webserver on 192.168.0.10 with notice board page saying this particular site is banned.

Comment: i know that way but its not working as some browser like chrome and Firefox show that this is error in certificate and that there is some one make mitm attack any ideas for the https

Comment: @ZamlkawyAna, DNS spoofing and https are two separate topics. You asked as of how you can block websites with dnsmasq, for which you got the answer. For HTTP, which most of the users type in their browsers get  your custom page. HTTPS traffic get error but doesn't get bypassed to the site. If you really want a custom page for HTTPS too, look at the possibility of authentication based WEB proxy.